# Regex: finding a string with an undetermined amount of words

Tags: regex, string, tags, grep

I have a tag that is like

```
tag="text textwithdot. text text"
```

followed by a further tag that would resemble

```
tag="text text text"
```

I wanted to use the following regular expression

```
tag="\w+"
```

but that only finds one word, how do I find the whole string within the quotes, what wildcard does that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
tag="([^"]*)"
```

That basically means `tag="` followed by zero or more characters that are not a double quote, followed by a double quote.

BTW: I'm assuming that there is no such thing as a tag that contains the double quote character. If there is such a thing, it would need some escaping rule applied to it and the regular expression would be more complicated.

Comment: this is what I needed, although I didn't need the () since I wasn't replacing it. I was deleting these tags but needed to find them all :) Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Also,
`tag=['"]([^"]*)['"]`
if that tags could change between ' and "

Comment: So what happens on this input: `tag='height 7" tall'`?

Comment: it would match `tag='height 7"`. If you do think it could contain quotes use the following which matches one or the other: `tag=('([^']*)'|"([^"]*)")` would return `tag='height 7" tall'`

Answer (score 0):

You could use an ungreedy match everything.

```
tag="[\s\S]*?"
```

Or use the `.` with *dot matches newlines* flag (assuming `\n` is a possibility).